# Output from the sheet without repetitions

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having a problem with the output in datagridview. I have a list of values ​​(for example / 1/3/5) and I need to display the names of objects that have at least one match with one of the digits. However, some objects have several matches and because of this they are displayed more than once, this is what I need to fix.

To select each element that I need to search for, I use a `foreach`. And in order to select the elements that have already been displayed, I created two sheets. In `pruv` I put all the elements that come in, and in `pruv2` I put elements that were not previously displayed. To compare the elements of these sheets, I wrote a `for`-loop. But at the moment the displayed objects are displayed several more times.

```
public static DataTable table = new DataTable();
public static DataTable tages = new DataTable();
**********************************************************************************************
DB.conetc();

table = new DataTable();
string sql = "SELECT history FROM users WHERE login= '" + nameuser + "';";
DB.usradapt(sql, 2);
string[] histor = table.Rows[0]["history"].ToString().Split('/');



List<string> pruv = new List<string>();
List<string> pruv2 = new List<string>();
pruv2.Add("0");

table = new DataTable();
foreach (var word in histor)
{
    int count = 0;
    sql = "SELECT NameFilm FROM films WHERE tags LIKE'" + $"%{word}%'";
    DB.usradapt(sql, 3);

    pruv.Add(tages.Rows[count]["NameFilm"].ToString());


    for (int i = 0; i < pruv.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pruv2.Count; j++)
        {
            if (pruv[i] != pruv2[j])
            {
                pruv2.Add(pruv[i]);
                DB.usradapt(sql, 2);
            }
        }
    }
    count++;

}

dgvResult.DataSource = table;
dataGridView1.DataSource = tages; //I display pruv content to understand what's inside

DB.connection.Close();
**********************************************************************************************
 public class DB
    {
        public static SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(); 
        public static void usradapt(string sql, int f)
        {
            SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, DB.connection);
            if (f == 1) { adapter.Fill(FormLogin.table); }
            else if (f == 2) { adapter.Fill(FormPage.table); }
            else if (f == 3) { adapter.Fill(FormPage.tages); }

        }
    }
}
```

Users have a history that records tags when searching for a movie:

[image: screen1]

Each movie has its own tags:

[image: screen2]

The left screen table:

[image: screen3]

should display the names of films that have at least one of the story tags. In theory, they should be displayed as in the right table, but in such a way that the same movie does not appear multiple times

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result.. (reading your code is not clear  what is the cause for the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing ProductA and then calling it instead of "for"

```
        public class ProductA : IEquatable<ProductA>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool Equals(ProductA other)
        {
            if (other is null)
                return false;

            return this.Name == other.Name;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as ProductA);
        public override int GetHashCode() => (Name).GetHashCode();
    }
                for (int i = 0; i < pruv.Count; i++)
            {
                ProductA[] storeA = { new ProductA { Name = pruv[count] } };
                ProductA[] storeB = { new ProductA { Name = pruv2[i] } };
                bool equalAB = storeA.SequenceEqual(storeB);

                if (!equalAB)
                {
                    DB.usradapt(sql, 2);
                    pruv.Add(pruv2[i]);
                }
            }
```